# C++ Formatting one-line brace-enclosed statements

Tags: c++, clion, clang-format

My team's convention is to always use braces with conditions and loops with a line break before the opening brace, but for one-line statements we don't include any line breaks between braces. For example:

```
if( condition )
{ doIt(); }
```

We use clang-format to auto-format our code, but as far as I can tell this isn't a convention that clang-format can handle. The result is that I have to be very careful not to auto-format entire source files or I'm stuck fixing every one-line `if`, `else`, `for`, etc. I've found myself undoing the same auto-formatted lines in the same source files repeatedly.

I've just started using CLion, and I can easily enough set up its default formatting to match what we do with clang-format, but I still can't figure out how to match our brace-enclosed one-liner convention.

Is there a way to tell either CLion or clang-format to do this? The obvious solutions would be to either avoid auto-formatting altogether or convince my team to adopt a convention that's easier to accommodate, but neither is an option (they're a very nit-picky bunch with very firm opinions about code style).

Comment: Well as a side note I hate it. But conventions are in place for a reason. Once they are in place it is usually hard to get them undone. :-(

Comment: I also hate this convention.  If your team is so strongly opinionated about coding convention, they should pay attention to the fact that in this instance they're enforcing a style that is not widely used anywhere.  As a result, people will find it more difficult to read code.  And even worse, it will begin to pollute other code bases as people who are forced to use this style will inevitably use it out of habit in their personal code or in other projects.

Answer (score 0):

- You cannot follow the

  if( condition )
  { doIt(); }

  convenion in CLion native formatter, sorry.
- CLion supports `clang-format` from the box.